# R define a function attribute inside the function

Tags: r, function, attr

Is it possible to R define a function attribute inside the very function?
It can be defined outside, but is there a notation for self-reference inside a function?

```
f2 = function(x) {
   x/2
   attr(thisObject(),'type')='half' #something like thisObject()
}
```

It is easy to do this outside the function:

```
attr(f2,'type')='half'
```

In a situation, I need to know what kind of function is passed by:

```
fCalc=function(f=f2,x){
  if(attr(f,'type')=='half') {
    cat('ok\n')
    return(f(x))
  } else cat( 'not ok')
}
fCalc(f2,4)
ok
[1] 2
```

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the use case for this.

Comment: Your situation doesn't explain why you need to define the attribute inside the function, as opposed to outside the function.

Comment: Cause everytime I edit the function I have to remember to redefine the attribute. Sometimes I forget...

Comment: There is a form of self-reference inside a function. Look at `?Recall`. Whether it handles your use case is not yet clear.

Comment: I can not figure out how to use it.  Neither `Recall(attr(ModeloGAMBoost,'tipo')='GAMBoost')` nor `attr(Recall(),'tipo')='GAMBoost'` worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write Java programs in R, you can define a function factory:

```
fact <- function(args, expr, attrib)
{
    f <- function() { }
    formals(f) <- args
    body(f) <- substitute(expr)
    attr(f, "type") <- attrib
    f
}

fact(alist(x=), x/2, "foo")
```